# Cookie not being set with browser

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cookies, axios, setcookie

i am trying to store the cookie sent from the response from server into my cookie storage. Unfortunately, when i try to make the request to the server it send back a response with a set-cookie header with `httponly,secure`, but the cookie is not being set. Just to provide more information, when i send the request i have attached it with `withCredentials:true`. I tried different solutions available online but it is not working. I would be glad if anyone could provide some help.

Comment: Is this a cross-site request?

Comment: yes it is a cross site request

Comment: Cross-site requests in modern browsers also require cookie to have the `SameSite=None` option set to allow saving the cookie across different sites